# How to calculate limits of sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Calculate the limits of the following sequences
> $$ a_n = \frac{n+4n-n^5}{n^3+3n^5-2n}$$
> $$ b_n =  \sqrt{n^2+4} - \sqrt{n^2+2} $$

I know the formulas to transform sequences to find out its limit but I do not understand to which point one has to transform a sequence to see its limit. I mean the limit of $a_n$ seems to be $- \frac{1}{3}$ and the limit of $b_n$ seems to be $0$ by just looking at them. I did not calculate anything. So I wonder to which point I have to transform sequences to "see" their limits. Can anyone explain me what the goal is when it comes to calculate limits of sequences?

Comment: What you need is just to calm down and carefully think of what you did (you actually did some calculation, you're just not aware of it!) to get the *correct* limiting values. Then just formalise your intuition!

Comment: I think you should clarify your question. From what you have written, it seems that you are aware of how to calculate the limit of a sequence (you have the correct limits written down).

Comment: @Carlo It was a question of understanding. I mean I just could say the highest exponent is 5, so everything else can be ignored. In the denominator $3n^5$ and in the numerator $-n^5$. So we just have to consider $\frac{-n^5}{3n^5}$ so the result  would be $\frac{-1}{3}$ because $\frac{n^5}{n^5}=1$ but that reasoning would not be enough. So I wondered to which point I have to transform the sequences (in general) such that the reasoning is enough to conclude the limit - that was the intent of this question

Comment: The same for $b_n$. Just ignore $+4$ and $+2$ because n goes to infinity. That means we would have the same expression on both sides and we know that $x-x=0$, so the limit must be $0$. Here are a lot of different answers with the same conclusions. So, since my intuitive reasoning would not be enough, I wonder to which point I have to transform the sequences such that the conclusion (limit) is based on a valid reasoning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one, divide the numerator and the denominator by the dominant power of the numerator that is $n^5$ in this case:
$$\begin{align}
\lim a_n &= \lim\frac{n+4n-n^5}{n^3+3n^5-2n} \\ 
&= \lim \frac{\color{blue}{5/n^3} - 1}{\color{blue}{1/n^2} + 3 - \color{blue}{2/n}} \\ 
&=\frac{-1}{3}\end{align}$$
because all blue terms tend to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

For the second one, here is the hint:
$$b_n =  \sqrt{n^2+4} - \sqrt{n^2+2} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{n^2+4} +\sqrt{n^2+2}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Numerically, the most dominant term in the numerator of $a_n$ is $-x^5$ and in the denominator it is $3x^5$, so the $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=-\frac{1}{3}.$$

Next $$L=\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n= \lim_{n \to\infty}[\sqrt{n^2+4}-\sqrt{n^2+2}]= \lim_{n\to \infty} n[(1+4/n^2)^{1/2}-(1+2/n^2)^{1/2}].$$
Use binomial expansion $(1+z)^k =1+kz+k(k-1)z^2/2+.... |z|<<1$
Then $$L=\lim_{n\to \infty} n[1+2/n^2+...-1-1/n^2-...]=\lim_{n \to \infty}n/n^2= \lim_{n \to \infty}1/n=0$$

Answer (score 1):

For $b_n$, Consider $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$  on $[n^2+2, n^2+4]$. Note that $f$ satisfies the hypothesis of mean value theorem. Then there exist $c \in (n^2+2, n^2+4) $ such that $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{c}}=f'(c)=\frac{\sqrt{n^2+4}-\sqrt{n^2+2}}{2}$$ So $$0<\sqrt{n^2+4}-\sqrt{n^2+2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}$$The result follows by Squeeze theorem!